# Dell laptop doesn't wake from hibernation after installing Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, laptop, hibernate, windows-8.1

My laptop worked flawlessly before upgrade to Windows 8.1 from 8. Now when I close the lid of my laptop and it goes into hibernation, it will not wake again. The LED lights seem to work properly but I don't get any video. I have to hold the power key to turn off then turn it back on again.

It wakes from sleep properly.

All Windows Updates have been installed. There are 2-3 items in the Device Manager that do not have compatible 8.1 drivers, but I believe those are security related items like fingerprint scanner.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you say "close my laptop" do you mean close the lid of the laptop?  You haven't really shared what you've attempted already.  What OS did you upgrade *from*? After you upgraded, did you go to the manufacturer's website and get updated drivers from them?  If you manually hibernate it, does it behave the same way?  If you disable all start up apps and 3rd party services, does it behave the same?

Comment: Does this problem also occur if you manually send it into hibernation using the Power menu under the Settings charm?

Comment: @K.A no, it seems specific to closing/opening lid.

Comment: While you're at it, please also check if your graphics card is AMD.

Comment: Check your power settings don't set the machine to shut down on lid close...

Answer (score 0):

This is something of a longshot, but try disabling hibernation, restarting, reenabling hibernation, restarting, and trying the open/close process again. It's possible the hibernation file is corrupted somehow and on trying to restore it, Windows dies.

- Open a command prompt with Administrative rights and type "powercfg -h off"
- After a restart, see if hiberfil.sys exists in the root of the C: drive (if so, the previous step didn't work)
- Open another administrative command prompt and run "powercfg -h on"
- After a restart, hiberfil.sys should be back.

Now try closing the lid and waiting a few seconds after it turns off before opening the lid again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a host of devices which are involved in sleep/wake process in Windows. SO off the top of my head the not compatible devices you mentioned may very well be the problem. I can't think of device more relevant to that than a fingerprint reader and/or "other security related items"...

What you should do is to make sure your devices' drivers are all updated.
Second thing to check is the BIOS version. look up your machine on Dell site using your Service Tag and see if there is newer version of the bios. Windows 8.1 is not WIndows 8 and usually there was a BIOS update to go with the 8.1 update.

Other things to check are USB devices - unplug everything and try again hibernate/wake the system.